# What is wrong with this Java class?

Tags: java, variables

Every time I create a new Dog object on a main Java class, I am unable to replace "null" (which represents the String Name variable from the Dog class) with the string I want. Here is the Class:

```
private String Name;
private int Age;

public Dog(String Name, int Age) //Constructor {
    this.Name =(String) Name;
    this.Age = Age;
}

public int getAge() {
    return Age;
}

public void setAge(int Age) {
    this.Age = Age;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String Name) {
    this.Name = Name;
}
```

Comment: What's the error message you get, and are these methods declared inside the "Dog" class? I assume they are, but you didn't include the actual class definition.

Comment: Can you show how you are using the class?

Comment: How are you saying that you are unable to replace the null, can you post an example of how you are doing that. Also this cast is unnecessary this.Name =(String) Name;

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need to cast from a `String` to a `String`, and having member vars/parameters with upper-case names goes against convention and is a little confusing.

Comment: How do you instantiate the Dog object? Do you set the name through the set method?

Comment: Please provide an SSCE ( http://sscce.org/ ) - code that people can compile and run to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It works for me.  What method are you using to test it, what output are you getting, and what output do you expect?

Comment: Please post *full errors*, especially when they are syntax errors. If there are no errors, but "it just doesn't work", then post a minimal test-case showing such. In both cases, please make sure the code is *valid*.

Comment: the message i get when i create the Dog object is "Cannot find Symbol. Symbol:Variable james" (James=replacement for null).

Comment: just post the code where you create instance of the Dog class...

Comment: Dog dog1 = new Dog(James, 2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Dog dog1 = new Dog("James", 2);` instead. The string literal has to be enclosed in double quotes, else, it'll be treated as a variable.

or, add

> String James = "Name of the dog";

before instantiating the Dog with `Dog dog1 = new Dog(James, 2);`

Answer (score 6):

You made your opening brace of your constructor to a comment:

```
public Dog(String Name, int Age) //Constructor { <-- Brace is part of comment
```

Solution:

```
public Dog(String Name, int Age) /*Constructor*/ {
```

Comment: even if the comment is set properly, the Dog object still does not allow me to replace "null"

Answer (score 2):

well, you have variables starting with Capitals, you have commented out a bracket at the constructor definition, you do unnecessary String casts...

Possible fixing option -> create your class like this:

```
public class Dog { 

private String name;
private int age;

}
```

Then, from your IDE, go to code generation options -> Choose generate getters and setters for both fields. Choose constructor generation with parameters. Done.

Answer (score 0):

nice :)

> public Dog(String Name, int Age) //Constructor {

http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc4.html

Comment: That is not the main point. Even if the comment was set like that, When I create a new Java main class I am unable to create the "Dog" object. I get the message "Cannot find symbol. Symbol: Variable James"